# Autoloading classes using class << self in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, metaprogramming

I have the following 3 files:

**test.rb**

```
# doesn't work, raises error: NameError: uninitialized constant Baz
Foo::Bar.do_stuff_1

# does work
Foo::Bar.do_stuff_2

# does work
Foo::Bar.new.do_stuff_3
```

**bar.rb**

```
module Foo   
  class Bar    
    class << self    
      def do_stuff_1

        puts "class level: #{Baz.new.class}"

      end    
    end

    def self.do_stuff_2

      puts "class level: #{Baz.new.class}"

    end

    def do_stuff_3

      puts "Instance level: #{Baz.new.class}"

    end    
  end    
end
```

**baz.rb**

```
module Foo    
  class Baz   
    def initialize

    end    
  end    
end
```

The `do_stuff_1` method raises an exception, **NameError: uninitialized constant Baz**, while the other methods are executing normally. I think it has something to do with `class << self ... end` adjusting the metaclass and `def self.method ... end` adjusting the class itself.

I would like to know if there is way to make `class << self ... end` autoload the Baz class appropriately like `def self.method ... end`.

I'm using Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.0.0 and I'm autoloading the classes using application.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an autoload problem per se, but rather a matter of namescopes. In the case of the first method, you're in the singleton class of `Bar`, so you need to reference `Baz` as `Foo::Baz`.

If you wanted to reference `Foo::Baz` from that context without using the name `Foo`, you use any expression that evaluates to `Foo` in that context, such as `Module.nesting[2]`, as in:

```
puts "class level: #{Module.nesting[2]::Baz.new.class}"}
```

Comment: Is there a way using `class << self ... end` and not referencing `Baz` as `Foo::Baz`?